# Passing file variable in GitlabCI to Docker run (FileNotFound)

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I created a protected file variable in GitlabCI so that the name is set to `GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS` and the value is the contents of the JSON file that serves as my Google Cloud service account key.

According to the documentation, it's possible to use this file variable in any commands so I use the following:

This is the contents of my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
stages:
  - build_image

image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

build_image:
  stage: build_image
  script:
    - docker build . -t johndoe/project_name
    - docker run --volume ${PWD}:/src --env=GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS johndoe/project_name
```

My Dockerfile (just in case):

```
FROM python:3.7-slim as builder
RUN apt update && \
    apt install --no-install-recommends -y build-essential gcc
COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --user -r /requirements.txt

COPY . /src
WORKDIR /src
ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "run.py"]
```

This is the part of the code where the key is used:

```
    try:
        key_path = os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]
    except KeyError:
        key_path = "./bigquery_key/key.json"
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        key_path,
        scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],
    )

    client = bigquery.Client(
        credentials=credentials,
        project=credentials.project_id,
    )
```

The error I get is the following:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/builds/johndoe/project_name.tmp/GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS'`

Using `echo` and `cat` shows that the file does exist and the contents exactly match the JSON file with the key, but for some reason, the Docker container doesn't know it exists.

What am I missing here?